# ant design blur method for InputNumber component

Tags: antd

I wanna use blur method to run a function if InputNumber component lost focus, but I don't know how to use it.

```
<InputNumber
value={value}
onChange={this.handleChange}
onKeyDown={this.onKeyHandler}
size="small"
min={0}
step={0.5}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this.

```
 <InputNumber
    value={value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyHandler}
    size="small"
    min={0}
    step={0.5}
    ref={(input) => this.testInput = input}
    />
```

Then inside lifecycle method like componentDidUpdate

```
 this.testInput.focus();
 this.testInput.blur();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way
It works fine. ;)

```js
<InputNumber
    value={value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyHandler}
    size="small"
    min={0}
    step={0.5}
    onFocus={this.showValue}
    onBlur={this.showValue}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onBlur` method and get the value in `event.target.value`.

```
onBlurHandler = e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  console.log(value) // entered value when input out focused

  // your logic
}

<InputNumber
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  onKeyDown={this.onKeyHandler}
  onBlur={this.onBlurHandler}
  size="small"
  min={0}
  step={0.5}
/>
```